# Sphinx search from text with special characters

Tags: sphinx

Please help me on sphinx search with extended search mode - I need to find "fathers day" query string from "Today is fathers's day" text. While searching, this text was ignored because of single quote in it. Is there any way to retrieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If really talking about `father's`, (ie `fathers's` is just a typo in your post); one possibility, is to add quote to `ignore_chars`

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-ignore-chars

During indexing it will 'disappear', so  `Today is father's day` would simply be indexed as  `Today is fathers day`

---

Really dealing with `fathers's` is a more tricky. Possibly fix it up with regexp_filter.

```
regexp_filter = (\w)s's\b => \1s
```

May want to combine this with morphology - ie a stemmer. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology

Comment: Great thanks for your help. I will follow these steps. :)